# Power BI Pro Licence with Office 365 Developer Account

Tags: office365, powerbi, licensing

I have an Office 365 Enterprise E3 Developer subscription and have been using Power BI Pro for the 60day trial - all good so far.

However it them seems to be impossible to buy a paid instance of Power BI Pro (there are options for Power BI Premium in my Admin portal Add subscriptions but not Pro).

MS support seem incapable of helping - has anyone overcome this issue?

Comment: I have engaged with MSOffice365 & Power BI support teams and it appears that this is by design - An O365 E3 Developer tenant is not able to buy Power BI Pro - not sure how I am therefore supposed to develop BI products...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software licensing are [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/6471538).

Answer (score 0):

Usually this would be managed through the Office 365 Admin Portal (not the Power BI Admin Portal).  Here's the usual link:

https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/subscriptions

You'll need to be the Office 365 Admin for your tenant.

Comment: In the Office365 admin portal there are options to purchase various BI Premium productions but not PowerBI